# Error in Java code StdRandom.uniform

Tags: java, operations-research

I'm trying to run java code using eclipse. I'm running this code:
http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/65reductions/Simplex.java.html
I got error in line 317/ 319/ 322 as "StdRandom Cannot be resolved"

Comment: Maybe you should get StdRandom.java from their website: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/StdRandom.java.html ?  While you're at it, get StdOut.java too: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/StdOut.java.html.

Answer (score 0):

Get the `StdRandom` from princeton's repository [here](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/StdRandom.java.html), then compile it along with your Simplex.java